# How to code a user input textbox in HTML and use javascript to show an explanation if the answer is correct otherwise say incorrect

Tags: javascript

I want to code this for my website so I can show the explanation for a problem only if a user input is correct otherwise, it should say that I am incorrect. I want to know what functions I need for this and how to code the HTML5 part of it.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'm afraid this is a bit too broad. Can you post an attempt at solving this and make the question a little more focused and concrete? See [ask] and [mcve]. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Do you want something like this ?

```js
let answer = "washington";

const input = document.getElementById("input");
const button = document.getElementById("checkAnswer")

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (input.value.toLowerCase() === answer) {
    alert("you are right")
  } else {
    alert("you are incorrect")
    input.value = ""

  }
})
```

```html
<p>where is the capital of america?</p>
<label for="input">Your answer</label>
<input type="text" id="input">
<button type="button" id="checkAnswer">Check</button>
```